# Creating a function in R to subset and run AUDPC analysis

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I am trying to run an AUDPC analysis on some data.  The data needs to be split into treatments and replicate blocks for the analysis. Below I have tried to write a function with the aim of spliting the data analyzing and ending up with the output of all treatment-blocks in one table/object

```
library("agricolae")
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
data = read.csv("Bio2018.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
data$Treatment = as.character(data$Treatment)
data$Block = as.character(data$Block)
data$Time = as.numeric(data$Time)
AUDPC.rel = function(Treatment, Block){
  data.Treatment <- subset(data, data$Treatment == Treatment & data$Block == Block)
  AUDPC = data.frame(audpc(data.Treatment$Foci, data.Treatment$Time, type = "absolute"))
}
variables = expand.grid(Treatment = c(unique(data$Treatment)), Block = c(unique(data$Block)))
Relative.AUDPC = mdply(variables,AUDPC.rel)
Relative.AUDPC
```

The output always give the same number for all treatment-blocks. As shown:

> Treatment  -  Block -  evaluation
>      Non-treated   -   Rep.1 -  200;
>      Emerald        -  Rep.1 -  200;
>      Nortica        -  Rep.1 -  200;
>      Non-treated    -  Rep.2 -  200;
>      Emerald        -  Rep.2 -  200;
>      Nortica        -  Rep.2 -  200;
>      Non-treated    -  Rep.3 -  200;
>      Emerald        -  Rep.3 -  200;
>      Nortica        -  Rep.3 -  200;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider base R's `by` to subset a data frame by one or more factors such as *Treatment* and *Block*. And because `by` will return a list of data frames (output of function), run `do.call` to row bind all df elements to one final data frame.

Also, since `by` runs across multiple factors to split across all possible combinations, wrap a `tryCatch` for such special subset cases of zero rows that may raise an error of `audpc` call.

```
# BUILD FUNCTION TO RECEIVE SUBSET DF
AUDPC.rel <- function(sub) {    
  tryCatch(data.frame(Treatment = sub$Treatment[[1]],
                      Block = sub$Block[[1]],
                      Evaluation = audpc(sub$Foci, sub$Time, type = "absolute")),
           error = function(e)
                     data.frame(Treatment = sub$Treatment[[1]],
                                Block = sub$Block[[1]],
                                Evaluation = NA)
           )
}

# CALL BY(), PASSING SUBSETS TO DEFINED FUNCTION
df_list <- by(data, data[c("Treatment", "Block")], AUDPC.rel)

# BUILD SINGLE FINAL DF
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help.